# NullPointerException at adding int to ArrayList

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

I have a function which is supposed to work with given `ArrayList<String>` and return the output as `ArrayList<Integer>`. The problem is `NullPointerException` is raised on `hourList.add(hourInt);` and I don't know why.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> takeTime(ArrayList<String> logs)  {

    ArrayList<Integer> hourList=null;
    Integer hourInt;

    for(String line: logs) {

        String[] matrix = line.split(" ");     
        String[] hour = matrix[3].split(":");
        //  System.out.print(hour[0]+"\n");

       String s = hour[0].replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");

        hourInt = Integer.parseInt(s);
       System.out.print(hourInt+",");

        hourList.add(hourInt);   // <--- NullPointerException here
    }
  return hourList;  
}
```

`System.out.print(hourInt+",");`:

```
  0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10
```

Comment: A generic answer on NPE might be a good reference point but this question was specific to `ArrayList` and it's initialization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to construct your `ArrayList` while declaring it:

```
ArrayList<Integer> hourList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Otherwise `hourList.add` will give NPE since reference `hourList` is null.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the `ArrayList`:

```
List<Integer> hourList = new ArrayList<Integer>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a function of a null object. Try:

```
ArrayList<Integer> hourList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```